# Capture caret (^) with an awk regex

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I have output with this format:

```
/ignore-this/^/../I/want/this@ignore-this
```

I am trying to use an awk regex to capture the following:

```
../I/want/this
```

This wouldn't be particularly hard except that I cannot figure out how to properly escape the `^` so it is not interpretted as an new line or a not.  Below is what I have so far, it almost works except it prints out:

```
/ignore-this/^/../I/want/this
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f                                                                              
{
    if (match($0, "\^.*@")){
        print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that there is a subtle difference between a [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) and a [carrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot).

Comment: Thanks, caret was definitely what I wanted.

Comment: @Chriszuma yup, it gives this error "awk: ./example.awk:7: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[^].*@/"

Comment: what if you use `/\^.*@/` (no dbl-quotes, a true reg-ex). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility, using gawk:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/gawk -f
{
    if (match($0, /[\^]\/(.*)@/, pieces)) {
        print pieces[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer shellter's regex which is pretty much the same but slightly simpler:  /\^.*@/  This is pretty much the same so I'll mark this as my accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumption that you want to exclude the leading "^/" from what's printed, leaving only "../I/want/this". If you like, you can get the desired result using POSIX awk and @shellter's regex by fiddling with the substr() values.

Answer (score 2):

```
> echo '/ignore-this/^/../I/want/this@ignore-this' |\ 
awk -F"^" '{split($NF,a,"@");print a[1]}'
```

output:

```
/../I/want/this
```

This splits the input stream on all "^". Then it takes the last field and splits it on "@" and prints the first half of the string.

EDIT:
Or use:

```
awk '/\^/{split($0,a,"[@^]");print a[2]}' file
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think this will work for me though because my awk code has more code than what I've provided.  Changing the delimiter would break the rest of the stuff :(

Comment: This works, all you want to do is split a string matching "^" on two different characters. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nice!  In a lot of ways I see this as a simpler solution because it splits on 2 characters rather than dealing with a messier regex capture.  I accepted the other answer only because this question doesn't actually answer how to escape a ^, which future readers of this post would want to know.  Thanks again for the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'\\^|@' '{print $2}'
```

should work in this case

```
kent$  echo "/ignore-this/^/../I/want/this@ignore-this"\
        |awk -F'\\^|@' '{print $2}' 
/../I/want/this
```

Answer (score 0):

speaking of `awk` `regex` with carets `"^"`, this may look strange at first glance regarding why the latter one is valid for merely doubling the first `regex`:

> *invalid* ::  **`/[^]/`**
>
> **VALID** :: **`/[^][^]/`**

1st one is invalid for the obvious reason :

- lack of escaping for the stand-alone caret `^` inside a character class `[…]`

2nd one is valid cuz it actually stands for :

- anything except `]`, `[`, or `^`

The order actually matters here : write it as **`/[^[]^]/`** instead, and what happens is that `gawk` and `mawk` simply fail silently (or match something not at all close to what ur original intentions were) while `nawk` simply errors out

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '/ignore-this/^/../I/want/this@ignore-this' |
```

---

```
gawk NF=NF FS='.*\^|@.*' OFS=

mawk '$0=$2;' FS='[@^]'
```

---

```
/../I/want/this
```